# Why was my old question was marked as a duplicate of a newer question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

A question I asked 2 years ago 
[Robot is prize for winning arcade game, then tries to kill everyone?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26682)
was marked as a duplicate of a question asked a few hours ago
['90s kids movie about a game robot attacking people](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62154/90s-kids-movie-about-a-game-robot-attacking-people).

Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: The reason behind it is that the new one is more detailed than yours (not your fault, of course - ID regulations were less strict a couple of years back). But I still thought it was backwards too, so I did ask first what people thought on chat. If you think it's wrong, though, I don't mind reversing it.

Comment: Refer main meta post for this : [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha)

Comment: Whatever the community thinks is fine, just curious :)

Answer (score 13):

Duplicate voting is a matter of quality. Ideally, the question with the best quality should stay open. This depends on how it's written, any answers, and community reception (aka up/down votes). **The goal being that the best information be shared and the lesser one closed**.

Here,  both the question and answer are higher quality, and voting reflects that as well. Sucks to be your question, but on the bright side, it doesn't negatively affect you.

On more technically minded questions, sometimes answers or questions are moved or merged if both exhibit good information.